# wait until chain of child processes are complete with Q Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, q, child-process

I need to run a couple of childprocesses and wait until they are done, and instead of using a long chain of callbacks I'm using Q promises. However what ever I try, the childproccesses are executed and Q just continues without waiting for the results.

```
var clones = repositores.map(function (project) {
    return Q.Promise(function (fullfill, reject) {
        require('child_process').exec('cd ' + clonepath + ' && git clone ' + project.repourl, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log(stdout);
            if (err) {
                console.log(stderr);
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                fullfill();
            }
        });
    })
});

Q.all(clones).then(function(){
    console.log("Clones complete");
}).done();
```

This will give "Clone complete" and after comes the clone result.

I've tried with child_process.spawn, fork, exec, execFile with the same result both callbacks and event based.

I've also tried wrapping the Promises in a returned function.

Comment: You seem to want to wait until the `stdout` stream closes?

Comment: I've tried that with a spawn process. spawn.on("close"), with the same result.

Comment: Unless you are working with an older version of the API you want `return Q.Promise...` rather than `return new Q.Promise...`

Comment: Oh, must have missed that, thanks. Doesn't do anything for the result however..

Comment: In first of all use Q.allSettled() instead of all() of course if you don't want to fail aggregated promise on the first failed command.

also you may want to use "child-process-promise" wrapper instead of writing your own one.

Comment: have you verified that the simplest case runs with hard coded values? i.e. `child_process.exec...`.  In terms of making this the simplest case you could let the exec command set the directory with `.exec('git clone '+..., {cwd:clonepath}, function(err, stdout, stderr){...}`

Comment: @zamuka allSettled give the same result, I'll checkout the promise exec wrapper.

Comment: @bknights the exec works, the process continues async.

Comment: @zamuka the wrapper did it, thanks for the tip. However I would like to know why the above example don't work as expected.